# find left invariant vector fields

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lie-groups

I have a Lie group $\,\big(\,G,\,\circ\,\big)\,$ of $\,\mathbb{R}^3$ where the law $\,\circ\,$ is defined by

$$
\big(x,\,y,\,z\big)\circ\big(x',\,y',\,z'\big) = \left(x+x',\,z+z'+xy',\,y+y'\right)
$$

We denote the left-translation by $\,L_g: p \rightarrow g\circ p$.

Considering a tangent vector $\,v=\left(v_1,\,v_2,\,v_3\right)\,$ of $\,T_xG$,
we have $\left(dL_g\right)_e\left(v\right) = \left(v_1,\,v_3,\,v_2\right)\,$ where $\,e=\left(0,\,0,\,0\right)\,$ is the unit element of $\,G$.

I am looking for left invariant vector fields $\,X\left(p\right)=\big(a\left(p\right),b\left(p\right),c\left(p\right)\big)\,$ where $\,a,\,b,\,c\,$ are smooth functions of the coordinates $p=\left(p_1,\,p_2,\,p_3\right)$.

We want $\left(a,b,c\right)$ such that

$\left(dL_g\right)_e\big(X\left(p\right)\big) = X\big(L_g\left(p\right)\big)$

- $X\big(L_g\left(p\right)\big) = \big(a\left(\tilde p\right),\,b\left(\tilde p\right),\,c\left(\tilde p\right)\big)$ 
  and $\,\tilde p = \big(p_1 + g_1,\,g_3+p_3+g_1p_2,\,p_2+g_2\big)$
- $\left(dL_g\right)_e\big(X\left(p\right)\big) = \big(a\left(p\right),\,c\left(p\right),\,b\left(p\right)\big)$

... but I get stuck

Comment: I think you need to use either point $e$ or $p$ in the both sides of equation in the definition of left invariant. By definition, vector field $X$ is _left-invariant_ on a Lie group $G$ if $\;\forall\;a,b \in G\;$ we have 
$$
d\big(L_a\big)_b \big(X(b)\big) = X\big(L_a(b)\big) = X\big(a,b\big)
$$